# How to create a fake column name in laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a query that need to use fake column name in Laravel. The code was fine but the problems were `'"0" as lang_id',` and `'"0" as qst_story',`.

The reason why I need to do this, my previous table use the old column name. So I need to provide fake column name in order to match with my previous code.

Anyone can help me? Thanks.

Current code:

```
$question_content = DB::connection('mysql_pencil_content')
                ->table('cms_qst_master_content as qmc')
//                ->with(['ImageContentGallery'])
                ->leftJoin('cms_qst_explaination as exp','exp.explaination_id','=','qmc.content_explaination_id')
                ->where('qmc.question_id',$main['question_id'])
//                ->groupBy('lang_id')
                ->get(['qmc.*',
                    'qmc.content_id as qst_cnt_id',
                    'qmc.question_id',
                    'qmc.content_text as qst_cnt_text',
                    'qmc.content_option as qst_cnt_options',
                    '"0" as qst_story',
                    'exp.explaination_text as explanation',
                    '"0" as lang_id',
                    'qmc.content_image_id as image_id',
                    'qmc.dt_update'])->toSql();
        pre($question_content);
```

Problems:

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 729:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '"0"' in 'field list' (SQL: select `qmc`.*, `qmc`.`content_id` as `qst_cnt_id`, `qmc`.`question_id`, `qmc`.`content_text` as `qst_cnt_text`, `qmc`.`content_option` as `qst_cnt_options`, `"0"` as `qst_story`, `exp`.`explaination_text` as `explanation`, `"0"` as `lang_id`, `qmc`.`content_image_id` as `image_id`, `qmc`.`dt_update` from `cms_qst_master_content` as `qmc` left join `cms_qst_explaination` as `exp` on `exp`.`explaination_id` = `qmc`.`content_explaination_id` where `qmc`.`question_id` = 200001)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `DB::raw`

```
DB::connection('mysql_pencil_content')
                ->table('cms_qst_master_content as qmc')
//                ->with(['ImageContentGallery'])
                ->leftJoin('cms_qst_explaination as exp','exp.explaination_id','=','qmc.content_explaination_id')
                ->where('qmc.question_id',$main['question_id'])
->select('qmc.*',
        'qmc.content_id as qst_cnt_id',
        'qmc.question_id',
        'qmc.content_text as qst_cnt_text',
        'qmc.content_option as qst_cnt_options',
         DB::raw('0 as qst_story'),
         'exp.explaination_text as explanation',
          DB::raw('0 as lang_id'),
         'qmc.content_image_id as image_id',
        'qmc.dt_update'
 )
->get(
```

)

Answer (score 0):

I thing best way use Eloquent 
So Make Function in your Models

```
class YourModal {
.
.
   public function getFakeitAttribute(){
        return "Fake Column";
   }
.
.
}
```

and now used it

```
$whatever = YourModal::all()->first();

// set value to it
$whatever->fakeit = 'other Fake';

// get the data of fake field
echo $whatever->fakeit
```